# edit a .jpg file in preview

Tags: mac, macos

I have typed the name of a bird on a .jpg photo. I made a spelling mistake and tried to edit it. I can create a new text box but not edit the original. Is there a way to edit a text box once you have saved the file

Comment: A note: make sure you save a JPEG with exactly the same quality settings as you opened it with and when cropping only crop aligned to a 16x16 grid, otherwise you'll lose quality in the unedited areas.

Comment: You were working on a copy - not the original?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there is no way to edit the text after saving the image.

You may be able to revert to a previous version of the image, before the misspelt text was written:

1. Open the image in Preview.app
2. Select the menu item: **File > Revert To > Browse All Versions**